# Query with JOIN slow

Tags: php, mysql

why my query take about 2 minutes to process?

i need to take attribute from 8 table.

how can i join those table and make it a fast query?

the reason why i want to join those table is bacause i want to fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) from user input progCode

this is my query :

```
"SELECT DISTINCT a.`ProgCode`, a.`Program` 
   FROM (select `i`.`name` AS `LC`,`f`.`name` AS `Intake`,`a`.`student_id` 
   AS `student_id`,`b`.`matricNo` 
   AS `matricNo`,`b`.`name` 
   AS `Nama`,`a`.`sem_id` 
   AS `sem_id`,`c`.`name` 
   AS `Sessi`,`e`.`code` 
   AS `ProgCode`,`e`.`name` 
   AS `Program`,`a`.`sub_id` 
   AS `sub_id`,`d`.`code` 
   AS `SubCode`,`d`.`name` 
   AS `Subject`,`a`.`grade` 
   AS `grade`,`h`.`credit` 
   AS `CurrentCreditHour`,`g`.`totalcredit` 
   AS `TotalCreditHour`,`g`.`gpa` 
   AS `GPA`,`g`.`cgpa` 
   AS `CGPA` from ((((((((`admin_sub_mark` `a` join `enrl_student` `b`) 
     join `struc_session` `c`) 
     join `struc_session` `f`) 
     join `struc_subject` `d`) 
     join `struc_program` `e`) 
     join `admin_sem_wise_cgpa` `g`) 
     join `admin_sem_wise_gpa` `h`) 
     join `struc_learningcentre` `i`) 
  where ((`b`.`id` = `a`.`student_id`) 
  and (`d`.`id` = `a`.`sub_id`) 
  and (`c`.`id` = `a`.`sem_id`) 
  and (`e`.`id` = `b`.`program_id`) 
  and (`f`.`id` = `b`.`intake_id`) 
  and (`i`.`id` = `b`.`learningCenter_id`) 
  and (`a`.`student_id` = `g`.`student_id`) 
  and (`a`.`sem_id` = `g`.`sem_id`) 
  and (`h`.`student_id` = `g`.`student_id`) 
  and (`h`.`sem_id` = `g`.`sem_id`)) order by `b`.`name`) a  
  ORDER BY `Program` ASC"
```

this is my explain query:

id| select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra

1 | SIMPLE      | g     | ALL  | NULL          |NULL | NULL    | NULL| 6049 | Using              temporary;
                                                          Using filesort

1 | SIMPLE | h | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 6055 | Using where |

1 | SIMPLE | c | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 257 | educate_aeu2.g.sem_id 1

1 | SIMPLE | b | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 257 | educate_aeu2.h.student_id 1 Using where

1 | SIMPLE | f | eq_ref |PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 257 | educate_aeu2.b.intake_id 1

1 | SIMPLE | e | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 257 | educate_aeu2.b.program_id 1

1 | SIMPLE | i | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 257 | educate_aeu2.b.learningCenter_id 1

1 | SIMPLE | a |ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 17077 | Using where

1 | SIMPLE | d | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 257 | educate_aeu2.a.sub_id 1

Comment: Start by doing an EXPLAIN on the query and look at what indexes are/aren't being used

Comment: use index for appropriate fields...

Comment: MySQL can `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` your query better than we can, because MySQL already knows what the schema's look like

Comment: If you need data from 8 tables with 1 query, you should take a second look at your database. Are you sure you divided the data into a good structure of tables?

Comment: yes.. i can create a view with that query but the view is also slow.. so i decided to put that on php code.

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' to question titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retreiving a lot of fields in the inner select and doing a sort, then ignoring most of those fields and doing another sort. This will waste time

Quick clean up of the code gives:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   e.code AS ProgCode,
   e.name AS Program
FROM admin_sub_mark a 
JOIN enrl_student b ON b.id = a.student_id
JOIN struc_session c ON c.id = a.sem_id
JOIN struc_session f ON f.id = b.intake_id
JOIN struc_subject d ON d.id = a.sub_id
JOIN struc_program e ON e.id = b.program_id
JOIN admin_sem_wise_cgpa g ON a.student_id = g.student_id AND a.sem_id = g.sem_id
JOIN admin_sem_wise_gpa h ON h.student_id = g.student_id AND h.sem_id = g.sem_id
JOIN struc_learningcentre i ON i.id = b.learningCenter_id
ORDER BY e.name ASC
```

Not sure whether you need to access all the tables.

Further what indexes do you have on the tables? If a query like this is running slowly then the culprit is normally the indexes but without knowing what they are (or better, the output from an EXPLAIN) we will struggle to provide any useful help

Comment: Looking at the explain there seem to be a couple of issues. Firstly on admin_sem_wise_cgpa and admin_sem_wise_gpa you need indexes that will be used (probably a covering index on both student_id and sem_id). Also most of you keys seem to have a length of 257, which suggests that the id fields are stored in VARCHAR(255) fields, which is likely to be a lot slower than using INT primary keys.

Comment: how to create index for them? do i need to put in that query? or call the index in that query?

Comment: You need to modify the table to add an index - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. Now my query become fast and furious!